# How to get information which tests are required for specified scope

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, test-setup, cli, diff

our deployment pipeline works on diff. So every time only differences between source and target branch are deployed to environment. We are wondering if there is possibility to run only required tests for specified scope (diff) to speed up process.

Comment: This sort of "optimization" is generally not a good idea; dependencies on changed metadata can be hard to determine, since these can be dynamic (depending on how your code works). Personally, I wouldn't go there. Indeed, I wouldn't even write my own code to do a "diff" for deployment (if that is what you did) and instead rely, if possible, on `sfdx` source tracking capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for other vendor tools but Gearset (I'm a user, not an employee) has a feature in their CI/CD pipeline product/feature wherein you can have it calculate the "affected" tests for any given PR's set of apex classes being promoted through the pipeline.

I've used this extensively and it works well

Feature is called [Automatic Test Selection](https://gearset.com/blog/automatic-unit-test-selection-for-salesforce-deployments/)

Comment: Is it clever enough to mark all tests for run if say you add a Validation Rule?

Comment: @DavidReed - that's a good question and I think the answer is NO; changes to only non-Apex metadata would only run enumerated test classes or run all tests if specified in the CI/CD job - but I'll ask the vendor to clarify. I know I've changed classes+VRs in PRs and have never seen it coerce to run all tests